# Triggering Event When Audio Has Finished Playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have not seen much documentation on the `<audio>` tag in HTML5.  I am trying to trigger an event when audio has finished playing.

HTML:

```
<audio id="audio">
    <source src="'.$query['audioPronunciation'].'" type="audio/mp3">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

JavaScript / jQuery Play & Pause:

```
function audio() {
    if ($("#audioControl").hasClass("glyphicon-play")) {
        $("#audioControl").addClass("glyphicon-pause").removeClass("glyphicon-play");
        $("#audio").trigger("play");
    } else if ($("#audioControl").hasClass("glyphicon-pause")) {
        $("#audioControl").removeClass("glyphicon-pause").addClass("glyphicon-play");
        $("#audio").trigger("pause");
    }
}
```

JavaScript / jQuery, 'when ended'

```
$("#audio").addEventListener('ended', function() {
    alert("Audio has finished playing!");
```

});

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need the event listener, just:

```
var audio1 = document.getElementById("myAudio1");
audio1.onended = function() {
    alert("audio playback has ended");
};
```